# Rubygems update fails on strange ruby versions

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a gem ([atd](https://gitlab.com/thesecretmaster/atd)) and I just tried to get gitlab CI to run my tests on all versions of ruby my gem supports (2.2.2 - 2.4.0) including bugfix releases. I had [an issue (GitLab CI pipline link, see versions > 2.3.0)](https://gitlab.com/thesecretmaster/atd/pipelines/6319620) with the [rainbow](https://github.com/sickill/rainbow) gem not working with versions of rubygems older than 2.6.9 (current rubygems version is 2.6.10), so in my gitlab ci builds (basically docker containers) I tried to run `gem update --system` before `bundle install`, and that got rid of the rainbow error, but I got the following error when running `gem update --system` only on ruby versions 2.2.4 and 2.3.0, which is weird because there are 2 versions between those two, 2.2.5 and 2.2.6:

Source: [My GitLab CI pipeline](https://gitlab.com/thesecretmaster/atd/pipelines/6327698)

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.2.4 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.2.4 ...
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-1684988-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-machine-1486422765-ae1c6a3c-gce...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/thesecretmaster/atd'...
Checking out ebe7405a as development...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ gem install rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.10
1 gem installed
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /usr/local/bundle/gems/rubygems-update-2.6.3
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.10
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

I think it might have something to do with the rubygems version before the upgrade, but I'm not sure. I know it fails going from rubygems 2.6.3 to 2.6.10 for ruby 2.2.4 and 2.3.0.

Here is a table of passes and failures:

```
ruby -v | initial gem -v | ci pass/fail
=======================================
2.2.2   | 2.4.8          | pass
2.2.3   | 2.5.0          | pass
2.2.4   | 2.6.3          | fail
2.2.5   | 2.6.8          | pass
2.2.6   | 2.6.10         | pass
2.3.0   | 2.6.3          | fail
2.3.1   | 2.6.8          | pass
2.3.2   | 2.6.8          | pass
2.3.3   | 2.6.10         | pass
2.4.0   | 2.6.10         | pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satiate `gem update --system`'s desire for an update to `2.6.3` to exist you can run `gem install rubygems-update --version 2.6.3` which installs the code to update to 2.6.3, then you can force it to update to the right version by telling it to `gem update --system 2.6.10` (2.6.10 is the current rubygems version at time of writing).